# Abstract routing datasource with different Databases

Tags: java, spring, spring-orm

We have an application where we have implemented Abstract Routing Data source feature in dealing multiple data bases of same type mysql (jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test, jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test2).

Now we are going with different database which is DB2. so i was unable to find any samples for this scenario using abstract routing datasource.

Can anyone give any directions ?

This is my code block:

i have defined 3 datasources itemDataSource, custDataSource, orderDb2DataSource in dao.xml .

how to configure the second session factory to the the transaction manager ?

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.test.DatabaseRoutingDataSource">
        <property name="targetDataSources">
            <map key-type="com.test.dao.DatabaseType">
                <entry key="ITEM" value-ref="itemDataSource"/>
                <entry key="CUSTOMER" value-ref="custDataSource"/>
                <entry key="ORDER_DB2" value-ref="orderDb2DataSource"/>
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultTargetDataSource" ref="itemDataSource" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource" />
        </property>
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>/WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySqlDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- Added for DB2 Database -->
    <bean id="sessionFactoryDB2" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource" />
        </property>
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>/WEB-INF/hibernate.db2.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- Added for DB2 Database -->

    <bean id="transactionManager1"
         class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Hi! Did you found any solution?